# code for display of mbtiles in android using nutiteq

Tags: android, nutiteq, mbtiles

I am new to android.I have converted map to mbtiles format.Now I need to create a sample application using nutiteq to display mbtiles on mobile.Please explain me step by step by writing code for displaying map. Dont give me links of some existing projects because I don't understand them,and there must be many people who must be expecting a sample android app explained step by step, which displays mbtiles using nutiteq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know Android general app development. If not, there are many books and instructions available. Regarding Nutiteq and MBTiles:

1. [Nutiteq wiki](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki#getting-started-step-by-step) has instructions how to get started
2. To get Nutiteq SDK as minimum you need [nutiteq-sdk.jar](https://repository-nutiteq.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/nutiteq/nutiteq-3d-sdk/2.2.1/nutiteq-3d-sdk-2.2.1.jar), and [javaproj-1.0.6-noawt.jar](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/blob/master/HelloMap3D/libs/javaproj-1.0.6-noawt.jar) in your project libs folder
3. Copy MBTiles file to your device /sdcard folder (or elsewhere)
4. To replace online map with MBTiles you need to change map layer definition, replace `TMSMapLayer mapLayer = new TMSMapLayer(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, 0, "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/", "/", ".png");` with:

> ```
> try {
>   MBTilesMapLayer dbLayer = new MBTilesMapLayer(proj, 0, 19, 2, "/sdcard/mymaps.mbtiles", this);
>   mapView.getLayers().addLayer(dbLayer);
> } catch (IOException e) {
>     // means usually that given .mbtiles file is not found or cannot be opened as sqlite database
>     Log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
>     e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

Comment: I used the code you provided and the jar files mentioned but its not recoginzing "MBTilesMapLayer". Its showing that  "MBTilesMapLayer is not a resolved type." What may be the problem?

Comment: Right click your project Properties->JavaBuildPath->Libraries....add the jar files from the lib folder->Order and Export....check the jars and click OK