# why MBTilesMapLayer is not a resolved type?

Tags: android, nutiteq, mbtiles

I used the code provided in the below link and the jar files mentioned but its not recoginzing "MBTilesMapLayer". Its showing that "MBTilesMapLayer is not a resolved type." What may be the problem?

[code for display of mbtiles in android using nutiteq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180340/code-for-display-of-mbtiles-in-android-using-nutiteq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that MBTilesMapLayer is in AdvancedMap3D project (https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/tree/master/AdvancedMap3D) , not in core SDK. You can either clone the project and add it as Android project dependency, or generate JAR file from this with:

1. clone AdvancedMap3D project from the github.
2. create up-to-date jar file from this project with "mvn package".
3. if you use a layer with NDK part (OGR, GDAL, Spatialite), then copy .so files from libs/armeabi files to your project same folder also. MBTiles does not require this.